# How to do grid col generation?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

How to generate columns depending on the number of entries in an array?

Let's say I have 5 entries in the array, it should be generated in this way:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        2 of 2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        2 of 2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        1 of 1
    </div>
</div>
```

Accordingly, if there are 4 entries, then it should look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        2 of 2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        2 of 2
    </div>
</div>
```

**html:**

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col" *ngFor="let param of params">
            <div class="form-group required">
                <label class="control-label">
                    {{param.name}}
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="value">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier if first redesign the array little bit - like group it by index:

```
 this.params = this.params.reduce(
  function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
    if (currentIndex % 2 === 0)
      accumulator.push(array.slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + 2));
    return accumulator;
 }, []);
```

this will create nice structure for the html template

[image]

then in html template:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let param of params; let i = index">
  <ng-container
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="param.length == 1 ? single : double"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: param, idx: i }"
  >
  </ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #single let-option let-index="idx">
  <div class="col-lg-12" *ngFor="let col of option">
    {{ col | json }}
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #double let-option let-index="idx">
  <div class="col-lg-6" *ngFor="let col of option">
    {{ col | json }}
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dynamicdialog-demo-8md7ah?file=src/app/app.component.html)